# R - is it possible to save model definition without data?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, model, frontend

I have app that could calculate some defined models (let's say `lm` model). The app is hosted on the server. Now I would like to add functionality, that user could define "on the side" any model (`arima` or any defined by user), add it to app and then calculate estimates by using that model.

The best solution would be if user could define model on own R instance, export it to a file and import via front-end on the server. The best solution for me, because user don't have to have any permissions to the server.

I was thinking about saving model definition as a RDS file and then importing it to app. However if model is saved via:

```
modelTest <- glm(y ~ x, data = df)
saveRDS(modelTest, file = "modelTest.rds")
```

And then after import:

```
modelTest2 <- readRDS("modelTest.rds")
df2$prediction <- predict(modelTest2, newdata=df2)
```

In the above example, the whole glm object is saved. It means that predicted values are also saved, so the file could be large if many predicted values are saved. Is it possible to use another method and save model with only model definition without data?

Comment: Not a direct solution with vanilla R, but you could look into using the [parsnip modelling framework](https://tidymodels.github.io/parsnip/articles/parsnip_Intro.html). They separate the model definition step from fitting it, so that could work quite well here, if your users can adopt this different workflow.

Comment: Not perfect, however I must consider it.